# What are the proper venues to talk about the ethics of software engineering?

Tags: publications, ethics, conference, computer-science, engineering

I am sure we all know about codes of ethics such as the "Software Engineering Code of Ethics and Professional Practice", and "ACM Code of Ethics and Professional Conduct". But as technology changes, we need to talk about new ethical challenges. I am having a hard time finding proper venues, such as (non-predatory) journals, or conferences in this topic. I am a little surprised that stackoverflow does not even have a tag for ethics or professional conduct, but I suppose nobody wants to talk about their ethical dilemmas in public.

So far I have found a [conference that seems legit](http://sites.ieee.org/ethics-conference/) but that is it.
I was hoping someone else out there knows about serious, sound, venues to discuss the ethics of programming, software engineering, computer science, in lieu of technological advances, if you do, I would appreciate your sharing of details about such venues.

Comment: _I am a little surprised that stackoverflow does not even have a tag for ethics_ I'm not, because that's not what stackoverflow is for (and many ethics questions that have been asked were closed as opinion based).  However, ethics questions are common on Workplace.SE.

Comment: Are you referring to scientific software engineering ethics specifically?  Then I have some possible venues.

Comment: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) has an ethics tag. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not questions about being a programmer or software engineer.

Comment: There's [ACM SIGCAS Computers and Society Newsletter](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=J198), but looks like there is [no current CFP](http://www.sigcas.org/newsletter/editorial-calendar). You could always [ask the editor](http://www.sigcas.org/officers-toc) what's going on with that..

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I am looking for anything in computer science, and software engineering ethics will help me greatly. Let me know what you have! I appreciate it.